# Powershell 3.0: Using my local profile and modules in remote PSSessions

Tags: powershell, remoting, remote-server

I need my local $profile located on my local PC to be loaded automatically when I PSRemote into other computers.  My $profile also imports a few local modules (available only on my local PC).  So, I need my $profile to be enhanced so that my modules can be still be imported (regardless where my $profile is loaded).

I spent a lot of time trying to get this to work; but see a lot of inconsistent information posted (probably because the differences between PS2 and PS3).  Everything I tried, resulted in some kind of error.

I was hoping someone would help me with a dummy-proof working example of how to do this.  The only thing that actually works is a basic: *enter-pssession -ComputerName RemoteServerName*.  I did try to at least get my local profile to load in a remote session (see below), but that didn't work either; let alone loading the modules imported in the profile file.

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name MyLocalProfile -StartupScript $Profile
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName REMOTESERVERNAME -ConfigurationName 'MyLocalProfile'
```

Gives error:

*Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server REMOTESERVERNAME failed with the following error message : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. Cannot find the MyLocalProfile session configuration in the WSMan: drive on the REMOTESERVERNAME computer.*

I even tried:

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name MyLocalProfile `
          -StartupScript \\MYLocalPC\profile$\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

But, but it still produced the same error. Not sure why it should be this hard to do something that most people would most likely want to happen by default.

Comment: Is S858AB1 the remote or local hostname?

Comment: Remote.  I just edited the first post with the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You're doing it incorrectly, and it's impossible to do it that way.

Long Answer:

From the [Enter-PSSession](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849707.aspx) page on MSDN, a line stands out:

`The session configuration for a session is located on the remote computer. If the specified session configuration does not exist on the remote computer, the command fails.`

Therefor you will have to `Invoke-Command` the `Register-PSSessionConfiguration` before creating the new session.

Comment: It looks like I didn't do a very good job of explaining the problem.  I started a new StackOverflow question that's much more concise; describing exactly what I've tried already; and, what specifically I can't do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130842/powershell-3-0-importing-binary-module-from-remote-share

Comment: Then please consider deleting this question.